# Can I add more than one object to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
weapons = {
    'sword' : {
        'damage' : 10,
        'type_damage' : 'sharp',
        'max_durability' : 20
    },
    'spear' : {
        'damage' : 7,
        'type_damage' : 'pointy',
        'max_durability' : 25
    },
    'log' : {
        'damage' : 5,
        'type_damage' : 'blunt',
        'max_durability' : 15
    }
}
inventory = {
    
}

inventory.update({'sword': weapons['sword']})
inventory.update({'sword': weapons['sword']})
```

I want to add two 'sword's to the inventory.

If I run this I get

```py
{'sword': {'damage': 10, 'type_damage': 'sharp', 'max_durability': 20}}
```

But I want

```py
{'sword': {'damage': 10, 'type_damage': 'sharp', 'max_durability': 20}}, {'sword': {'damage': 10, 'type_damage': 'sharp', 'max_durability': 20}}
```

If there's a way to do this, please let me know!

I tried making 'slots'

```py
inventory = {
'slot1',
'slot2'

inventory['slot1'] = ({'sword': weapons['sword']})
inventory['slot2'] = ({'sword': weapons['sword']})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll need to rethink how to keep track of inventory if you allow repeated entries.  ```inventory.update({'sword': <info>})``` will replace the current ```sword``` info.

Comment: Keys need to be unique in a dictionary.

Comment: Just have a list of slots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you have done because keys in a dictionary are unique, and adding a new entry with an existing key will just modify the value paired with that key.

So, you need to follow your slot idea by doing this:

```
inventory = {
   'slot1': {},
   'slot2': {}
}

inventory['slot1'].update({'sword': weapons['sword']})
inventory['slot2'].update({'sword': weapons['sword']})

print(inventory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only add one object per key to a `dict`, but you can add an object that holds other objects, like a `list` or `set`. You should be consistent, e.g always adding a `list` even if it's only one object, otherwise you need to add a lot of extra code to handle object versus list of objects.